# When a monoidal category is equivalent to its center

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

The notion of the center of a monoidal category categorifies that of the center
of a monoid. Similarly, the notion of a braided monoidal category is a categorification of that of a commutative monoid. Given a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, when the center  $Z(\mathcal{C}) \cong \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: it is known that $Vect_{\Bbb R}$ is monoidal category, what would be $Z(Vect_{\Bbb R})$?

Comment: I mean are there certain conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ by which we always have the case $ Z(\mathcal{C}) \cong \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42999/which-monoidal-categories-are-equivalent-to-their-centers). You can compute, for example, that if $X$ is a scheme then $\text{QCoh}(X)$ is naturally equivalent to its center. But this is in some sense an accident coming from not doing things in a sufficiently derived way.